# Group Pickup Scenario - CALL_STATE.CS_CONNECTED not being fired

Tags: cisco, tapi

We have a telephony scenario where a group of 5 emergency devices are all called at the same time in a group pickup configuration. There is a generic number which is called and then rings all the 5 devices, leaving to the operators the choice of what device will pickup the call.

The problem is: when a call is picked up in this scenario, I can't see the CALL_STATE.CS_CONNECTED event being fired. This event is being fired when I call directly any of the 5 extensions, but not when a group pickup occurs.

I'm using the Interop.TAPI3Lib.dll in a windows service application, here goes a piece of code that succesfully notifies the CALL_STATE.CS_CONNECTED event when I call the extensions directly:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private TAPI _clTapi;
    public ITTAPI gobjTapi1;
    public ITAddress[] gobjAddress1;
    public ITCallInfo gCall;
    public ITCallHub gHub;
    public ITCollection objCollAddresses;
    private ITCallStateEvent CallStateObject;

    //Service start/stop/abort routines goes here

    private void TapiEvents(TAPI_EVENT TapiEvent, object pEvent)
    {
        if (TapiEvent == TAPI_EVENT.TE_CALLSTATE)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.CallStateEvent));
            this.CallStateObject = (ITCallStateEvent)pEvent;
            thread.Start();
        }
    }

    private void CallStateEvent()
    {
        CALL_STATE state = this.CallStateObject.Call.CallState;

        if (state == CALL_STATE.CS_CONNECTED)
        {
            //Do something...
        }
        else if (state == CALL_STATE.CS_DISCONNECTED)
        {
            //Do something...
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: is there any specific treatment when dealing with pickup/connection events in group pickups?

Comment: Who are you monitoring in this scenario? Only the calls on the device making the call and the device who does the answer will get a connected event, the others will all go idle (including the group extension if it is a monitor-able device itself)

Comment: @KrisVanherck We are monitoring every device registered/available, including the ones making the calls and answering the calls. But after your answer, we realized that it may be a thread concurrency problem - our (legacy) code expects a single connected event and a single disconnected event "safely" aparted in time as they share the same CallStateObject.

Answer (score 1):

After some more tests, I found out that the problem was a thread concurrency between simultaneous CS_CONNECTED and CS_DISCONNECTED events. In this scenario, a call answer generates 1 connected event and N-1 disconnected events, where N is the number of devices being called.

Since there was only one CallStateObject to store call information, the threads were unsafely using this object at the same time and therefore "mixing" each other event values. Just by dealing with this concurrency problem, the problem was solved.